# How do I remove keyval options from a template class?

Tags: koma-script, key-value

I want to create a template class based on `scrreprt.cls` but with fewer options. Specifically, I need to restrict the font size to 11pt or 12pt (while still passing other options on to `scrreprt.cls` in the usual way). If a user tries to choose another size, the class should issue a warning and revert to the default setting.  I know how to do this if the options are given in the 'traditional' format, i.e.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{scrreprt}
```

but how do I deal with options given in keyval syntax, that is

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt]{scrreprt}
```

thesis.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{thesis}[2015/12/06 \space\space Ian Thompson]
%Need to restrict font size options here. 
\DeclareOption*{% 
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrreprt}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{scrreprt}
```

test.tex:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt]{thesis} % <--- Option should generate a warning  
\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see a completely different problem, as any user can set the fontsize (and basically everything else) after the documentclass or even in the middle of a document.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Besides that, the way KOMA hides the optioning system is a little bit weird.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What do you mean? This would be possibly better suited in chat.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion that makes the change to a prohibited font size value a little bit more difficult.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{MyClass.cls}
\ProvidesClass{MyClass}[2017/05/18]
\RequirePackage{scrbase}
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
%\providecommand*\Ifisdimension{\Ifisdimension}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif

\DefineFamily{MyClass}
\DefineFamilyMember{MyClass}
\DefineFamilyKey{MyClass}{fontsize}{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{12pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{fontsize=12pt}{scrreprt}%
    }{%
      \PassOptionsToClass{fontsize=11pt}{scrreprt}%
      \Ifstr{#1}{11pt}{}{\ClassWarning{MyClass}{font size `#1' is not supported}}%
    }%
  \FamilyKeyStateProcessed%
}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \Ifisdimension{\CurrentOption}{\OptionNotUsed}{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrreprt}}}
\FamilyProcessOptions{MyClass}
\LoadClass{scrreprt}
\let\@KOMAoption\KOMAoption
\renewcommand\KOMAoption[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{fontsize}{%
    \ifdim #2=12pt
      \@KOMAoption{fontsize}{12pt}%
    \else
      \ifdim #2=11pt
        \@KOMAoption{fontsize}{11pt}%
      \else
        \ClassWarning{MyClass}{font size `#2' is not supported}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }{%
    \@KOMAoption{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}
% disable \KOMAoptions
\renewcommand*\KOMAoptions[1]{%
  \ClassError{MyClass}{`\string\KOMAoptions` is not supported}{%
    Command `\string\KOMAoptions` is not supported by MyClass%
  }%
}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[fontsize=9pt,a5paper,DIV=calc]{MyClass}
\begin{document}
Hello. \KOMAScriptVersion

\KOMAoption{fontsize}{10pt}
Hello. \KOMAScriptVersion

\KOMAoption{fontsize}{12pt}
Hello. \KOMAScriptVersion
\end{document}
```

Note that it is still possible to change the font size to another value than `11pt` or `12pt` using `\usepackage[9pt]{extsizes}` or `\FamilyOptions{KOMA}{fontsize=9pt}` or using the command `\fontsize` or ...

---

Here is an additional suggestion by Markus Kohm that needs at least version 3.18.2144. The current version is available at the [KOMA-Script website](http://www.komascript.de/node/1801)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mythesis.cls}
\ProvidesClass{mythesis}[2015/06/18]
\RequirePackage{scrbase}[2015/06/17]
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
%\providecommand*\Ifisdimension{\Ifisdimension}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\BeforeFamilyProcessOptions[.scrreprt.cls]{KOMA}{%
  \expandafter\let\csname KV@KOMA.scrreprt.cls@font@size\expandafter\endcsname
                  \csname KV@KOMA.scrreprt.cls@fontsize\endcsname
  \DefineFamilyKey[.scrreprt.cls]{KOMA}{fontsize}{%
    \Ifstr{##1}{12pt}{%
      \FamilyExecuteOptions[.scrreprt.cls]{KOMA}{font@size=12pt}%
      \FamilyKeyStateProcessed
    }{%
      \Ifstr{##1}{11pt}{%
        \FamilyExecuteOptions[.scrreprt.cls]{KOMA}{font@size=11pt}%
        \FamilyKeyStateProcessed
      }{%
        \FamilyKeyStateUnknownValue
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \Ifisdimension{\CurrentOption}{\OptionNotUsed}{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrreprt}}}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{scrreprt}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[fontsize=9pt,a5paper,DIV=calc]{mythesis}
\begin{document}
Hello. \KOMAScriptVersion
\KOMAoption{fontsize}{12pt}
Hello. \KOMAScriptVersion
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt}
Hello. \KOMAScriptVersion
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the first example you are redefining `KOMAoptions` two times, if i looked correctly.